# ASP.NET MVC - get data from SQL Server with angularJS

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, database

I'm getting an error when I try to retrieve data from a SQL Server database and there is more than 1 table with a foreign key.

Controller:

```
private DbContext db = new DbContext();

public JsonResult GetAll()
{
        var result = db.Books.ToList();
        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Service.js:

```
var Service = {};

Service.getAll = function () {
        return $http.get('BooksModels/GetAll');
};
```

Controller.js:

```
getAll();

function getAll() {
    ToshokanService.getAll()

     .success(function (an) {
         $scope.books = an;
         console.log($scope.books);
     })
        .error(function (error) {
            $scope.status = 'Error' + error.message;
            console.log($scope.status);
        });
}
```

Error: "Errorundefined"

This works when I only have one table in database.

Is it a good idea to retrieve data from a database using AngularJS in ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: What's the error? at where exactly you are getting the error?

Comment: error: "Errorundefined". On GET http://localhost/BooksModels/GetAll

Comment: So you are having this problem when you have 2 tables in your database?  Did you debug your controller? Can you confirm your mvc controller is getting data from database when there are multiple tables?

Comment: Yes. I get the data in controller.

Comment: I'd suggest you debug your MVC controller first, see what's returned in `result`.

Comment: Its a best practice to do not return your context objects as they will probably have references you may not want so serialize or even circular ones. Normally you will be returning a new object built from the context one. Either by anonymous objects or some canned solutions like automapper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If error because table have foreign key, when return Json you should use "select from" like this

```
 public JsonResult GetLocationJson() {
            var result = (from p in General.DBCtx.Locations.ToList()
                          select new { ID = p.ID, Name = p.Name, Keyword = p.Keyword, Path=p.Path,Des=p.Descript,ParentID=p.ParentID }
                        ).ToList();
            return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

There are many way do fix that error but this is the simple way If you don't want to interfere Entity class by Assembly.

Comment: if you want to get data from other table , see in the ***
`var result = (from p in General.DBCtx.Locations.ToList()
                          select new { ID = p.ID, Name = p.Name, Keyword = p.Keyword, Path=p.Path,Des=p.Descript,ParentID=p.ParentID, ***parent= p.Location1==null?null:new {Id=p.Location1.ID,Name=p.Location1.Name }***, }
                        ).ToList();`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `then` instead of `success` ? Like so:

```
ToshokanService.getAll().then(function (an) {
         $scope.books = an;
         console.log($scope.books);
     })
```

You can read about it [here](http://www.codelord.net/2015/05/25/dont-use-$https-success/)